# Close Chrome Web Driver on Windows Form Closing

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a relatively easy question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Whenever I close my Windows Form with the Selenium Chrome Web driver open it will close the Windows Form/Application, but leave the Chrome console and browser open. Is there any way to use driver.Quit() or .Close(); when the form is closing? Something like my example below.

```
    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
driver.Quit();
driver = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that that event of closing the form is not catched when you are pressing close button.

You must subscribe FormClosing event and call also Quit method on driver.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        // (...)
        this.FormClosing += this.Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        driver.Quit();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Note that console of driver will be closed when you will run app with F5, but will not close when you will run by CTRL F5.